# queries of Foreinkey

Tags: django, django-queryset

i am currently trying to make a django project but i am stuck

```
class Klasse(models.Model):
    klasse = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.klasse


class Lehrer(models.Model):

    Name_und_Nachname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    Klassenlehrer_von = models.ForeignKey(Klasse, max_length=200, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name_und_Nachname



class Schüler(models.Model):

    name_und_Nachname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    Klasse = models.ForeignKey(Klasse, max_length=200, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    Klassenlehrer = models.ForeignKey(Lehrer, max_length=200, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_und_Nachname


class Punkte(models.Model):
    punkte_ang = (("0", 0),("1", 1), ("2", 2), ("3", 3), ("4", 4), ("5", 5))
    punkte_norm = (("0", 0),("1", 1))

    Soziales_angagement = models.CharField( max_length=200, null=True, choices=punkte_ang,)
    Lernverhalten = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=punkte_norm, )
    Sozialverhalten = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=punkte_norm,)
    konfliktlösung = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,choices=punkte_norm,  )
    eingentum_anderer = models.CharField( max_length=200, null=True, choices=punkte_norm,)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

so to the code i wanna say i know its not the most beautiful and not the best one.
So back to my question i need a way to connect the foreinkeys betwen the students = Schüler and the Teachers = Lehrer i thaught i could make this with querying the Klasses and if the student and the teacher have the same class they get linked.
is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the `Schüler` with a `Klasse` of some `Lehrer` named `mylehrer` with:

```
Schüler.objects.filter(Klasse__lehrer=mylehrer)
```

or vice versa you can retrieve all the `Lehrer`s of a `Schüler` named `myschüler` with:

```
Lehrer.objects.filter(Klassenlehrer_von__Schüler=myschüler)
```

There is thus no need to store these items with an extra field in the `Lehrer`/`Schüler` model, since the `Klasse` model acts as a [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) between the `Lehrer` and `Schüler` model.

Comment: Where does the "mylehrer" or "myschüler" come from?

Comment: @UnicornFart: these are the objects for which you want to determine the *related* schulers/lehrers from.

Comment: yeah but how do i have to make them(sorry if thats a stupid question but i dont use django for very long)